# Как с помощью request получить определенные данные из веб клиента comunda

Tags: python, requests, camunda

Сегодня первый раз столкнулся с библиотекой requests. Начал сразу читать руководство, но ничего не нашел, что мне нужно, видимо плохо искал.

Из этой веб-страниц мне нужно получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал через request.content/text, но не получилось

```
response = requests.get("http://192.168.11.169:8080/camunda/app/cockpit/default/#/process-definition/ec1cc3de-0cb3-11ec-9a90-0242ac1e0002/runtime?searchQuery=%5B%5D&viewbox=%7B%22Definitions_1%22:%7B%22x%22:131.88541666666666,%22y%22:-1001.4375,%22width%22:8979.166666666666,%22height%22:3125%7D%7D")
print(response.text)
```

Вывод:

```
D:\Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projects/test.py
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/camunda/app/cockpit/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Camunda Cockpit"/><title>Camunda Cockpit</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/camunda/app/cockpit/styles/styles.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/camunda/app/cockpit/styles/styles-components.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/camunda/app/cockpit/styles/user-styles.css"/><base href="/camunda/app/cockpit/default/" admin-api="/camunda/api/admin/" cockpit-api="/camunda/api/cockpit/" engine-api="/camunda/api/engine/" app-root="/camunda"/><link href="../static/css/main.87a496cd.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,a,p=r[0],l=r[1],c=r[2],i=0,s=[];i<p.length;i++)a=p[i],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,a)&&o[a]&&s.push(o[a][0]),o[a]=0;for(n in l)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l,n)&&(e[n]=l[n]);for(f&&f(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,c||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,p=1;p<t.length;p++){var l=t[p];0!==o[l]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=a(a.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function a(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,a),t.l=!0,t.exports}a.m=e,a.c=n,a.d=function(e,r,t){a.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},a.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},a.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=a(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(a.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)a.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},a.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return a.d(r,"a",r),r},a.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},a.p="../";var p=this["webpackJsonpcamunda-react-webapp"]=this["webpackJsonpcamunda-react-webapp"]||[],l=p.push.bind(p);p.push=r,p=p.slice();for(var c=0;c<p.length;c++)r(p[c]);var f=l;t()}([])</script><script src="../static/js/2.2c955996.chunk.js"></script><script src="../static/js/main.12f48097.chunk.js"></script></body><script>window.JAR_PLUGINS=[{ name: 'cockpit-plugin-cockpitPlugins', location: '/camunda/api/cockpit/plugin/cockpitPlugins/static/app', main: 'plugin.js' }]||[]</script></html>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Так же Пробовал вывести данные через json, чтобы в выводе было "ключ"-"значение", где и будут храниться мои данные, однако выдает ошибку.
Если подставлять одни url, то он спокойно все выводит, если другой, то появляется ошибка:

1)

```
    response=requests.get("http://192.168.11.169:8080/camunda/app/cockpit/default/#/process-definition/ec1cc3de-0cb3-11ec-9a90-0242ac1e0002/runtime?searchQuery=%5B%5D&viewbox=%7B%22Definitions_1%22:%7B%22x%22:131.96093749999997,%22y%22:-1002.015625,%22width%22:8984.375,%22height%22:4953.125%7D%7D")
print(response.json(), 'json')
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(response.json(), 'json')
  File "D:\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\olegl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\olegl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\olegl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

2. 

```
response = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
print(response.json(), 'json')
```

Вывод:

```
D:\Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Projects/test.py
{'args': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.26.0', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-613b6d62-41ab490e6ac92de17af8b2e8'}, 'origin': '31.173.85.113', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/get'} json

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! дайте пример запроса `requests`, который вы посылаете, а так же ответ, который вы получаете. Добавить можно в сам [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1327158/edit)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Олег На портале есть возможность вставлять код текстом, будьте добры исправьте вопрос. Вы можете вставлять любое необходимое количество кода. Просто используйте специальные блоки для этого.

Comment: используйте на реальной ссылке `response.status_code`, чтобы понять каков ответ от сервера. При ответе 200 можно обрабатывать уже содержание ответа. Для справки: ответ может быть не json().

Comment: @Dmitry , вопрос я изменил. При вызове метода **status_code**, выводится 200.
Если объект, который мы получаем не json, тогда как понять как с ним обращаться и извлекать из него данные?